# How to open an external URL in a modal from AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I want to use OAuth in my AngularJS application, and to do so I need to take the user to the Twitter OAuth page so that they can grant access. I could do this inside my application, but I'd prefer not to redirect the user out of the context of the Angular app (i.e. don't reload the page) and so what I want to do is open the authorization page in a pop-up or modal window. The user completes the workflow in that window and when they close the modal, the access token is stored in my app, or in a cookie.

I am really struggling to figure out how to open this pop-up and populate it with the Twitter grant authorization page.

```
> Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NeMAj32daePMopWaffkw?p=info
```

If you could get an external website to open in that modal then I think I might be part-way there?

Comment: You'll need to embed an iframe in the modal body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. Even if you could embed the Twitter auth page inside a modal's iframe, the OAuth flow would ways force it to redirect. Knowing that a redirect is applied to the entire page (e.g. browser window/tab) and not only to the iframe, it would end up redirecting your entire page.

[And there's also the phishing risk](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/526)

Your only option is to open a new browser tab/window(popup).

More information about Twitter's OAuth flows [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/browser-sign-flow) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter).